# paste header and first 2 rows with a new line in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, paste, cat

I have 3 rows

```
first <- LETTERS[1:9]
second <- c(1:9)
third <- letters[1:9]
> first
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"
> second
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> third
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"
```

I want the output vector of 9 elements with new line like that

```
"A    "B
 1     2
 a"    b"  and so on
```

I try to use loop but it doesn't work

```
y <-c()
z <-c()

 for(i in 1:length(first)){
  y <- paste(first, second, sep = "\n")
  z <- paste(y, third, sep = "\n")
}
```

I got out put

```
[1] "A\n1\na" "B\n2\nb" "C\n3\nc" "D\n4\nd"
[5] "E\n5\ne" "F\n6\nf" "G\n7\ng" "H\n8\nh"
[9] "I\n9\ni"
```

This is not give me a newline. The format of my colnames(data) for report need to be like that. Thanks for advance.

Comment: the first element will be A newline 1 and newline a, sep="\n", not give me newline

Comment: this is out put [1] "A\n1\na" "B\n2\nb" "C\n3\nc" "D\n4\nd"
[5] "E\n5\ne" "F\n6\nf" "G\n7\ng" "H\n8\nh"
[9] "I\n9\ni"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding you correctly that you are looking for this:

```
first <- LETTERS[1:9]
second <- c(1:9)
third <- letters[1:9]

cat(c(first, "\n", second, "\n", third))

A B C D E F G H I 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
a b c d e f g h i
```

?

EDIT: 
Will this solve your problem?

[Printing R data frame with column names in multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944082/printing-r-data-frame-with-column-names-in-multiple-lines)

Comment: yes, c(first, "\n", second, "\n", third) is a vector

Comment: it's not a vector, it doen't have "" for each, I can't get the first element

Comment: c(first, "\n", second, "\n", third)[1]  returns: "A".
It is a vector.

Comment: I try to add it with data frame, I have z <-c(1:9), I rbind it to z

Comment: z has length 9, c(first, "\n", second, "\n", third) has length 29, why would you want to rbind them? Let a <- c(first, "\n", second, "\n", third). Maybe you want to cat(c(a, "\n", z)). If not, I have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: I need to make cat() is colnames(data) with 9 columns, cat() give me a string. The first colnames is "A\n1\a" look like your output, the second colname(data) is "B\n2\b"

Comment: I think I finally understood your question. I edited my answer and added a link to another question already asked. Hope this helps.